# How to get Interstitial ad ID in LEADBOLT?

Tags: android, leadbolt

I want to try get Interstitial ad ID but i can't do that.
I have Banner ID.
How can i get Interstitial ad ID from LEADBOLT side.

PLEASE guide me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take some time to read the tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour  Also, you should provide more info on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question!

If you would like to implement Leadbolt ads using our SDK, please follow the integration guide for the appropriate framework, looking at the 'Add your Apps' and ‘Copy Your Integration Details’ sections. You can find our integration guides here: http://help.leadbolt.com/app-developers .

For more information for your specific situation, please contact us at support@leadbolt.com directly and quote your Publisher ID. We will be happy to assist you further.

Kind Regards,

Leadbolt Support Team